# Chrome: Switch from kiosk to desktop mode using a shortcut

Tags: google-chrome, browser

I start Chrome in Windows 7 in kiosk mode using a shortcut with the parameter `-kiosk https://example.org`. I can close Chrome using **Alt + F4**, but is there also a way to switch to standard desktop mode?

Answer (score 0):

you can switch to other programs by pressing

**ALT+TAB** or **Ctrl+ALT+DEL**

To access the desktop, you would have to exit chrome

use [vimium](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vimium/dbepggeogbaibhgnhhndojpepiihcmeb) to access address bar in chrome.

Here is optional [exitkiosk](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/exit-kiosk/oickijkfojmeggjbbhajnpjapbkippen) mode extension for chrome

Regards

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I need. I'd like to leave kiosk mode and access the 'standard' mode including an address bar. This mode is apparently called desktop mode. But it's nice to know **Alt + Tab** is working, I didn't expect that! This shortcut _does_ show the desktop.

Comment: Here is also useful link
https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/3134673?hl=en